# What is the maximum size of buffers memcpy/memset etc. can handle?

Tags: c

What is the maximum size of buffers [memcpy and other functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcpy#Functions) can handle? Is this implementation dependent? Is this restricted by the size(size_t) passed in as an argument?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is entirely implementation dependent.

This depends on the hardware as much as anything, but also on the age of the compiler.  For anyone with a reasonably modern compiler (meaning anything based on a standard from the early 90's or later), the size argument is a `size_t`.  This can reasonably be the largest 16 bit unsigned, the largest 32 bit unsigned, or the largest 64 bit unsigned, depending on the memory model the compiler compiles to.  In this case, you just have to find out what size a `size_t` is in your implementation.  However, for **very** old compilers (that is, before ANSI-C and [perhaps for some early versions of ANSI C](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/programming/ansic-library.html#string)), all bets are off.

On the standards side, looking at cygwin and Solaris 7, for example, the size argument is a `size_t`. Looking at an embedded system that I have available, the size argument is an `unsigned` (meaning 16-bit unsigned).  (The compiler for this embedded system was written in the 80's.)  I found a web reference to some ANSI C [where the size parameter is an `int`](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/programming/ansic-library.html#string).

You may want to see [this article](http://www.embedded.com/columns/programmingpointers/200900195) on `size_t` as well as the [follow-up article](http://www.embedded.com/columns/programmingpointers/201803576) about a mis-feature of some early GCC versions where `size_t` was erroneously signed.

In summary, for *almost everyone*, `size_t` will be the correct reference to use.  For those few using embedded systems or legacy systems with very old compilers, however, you need to check your man page.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this must not have been programming C long enough to be around when this wasn't so standardized.

Comment: Are pre-C89 compilers still common? I think it's pretty safe to depend on size_t, excepting work on legacy systems.

Comment: I downvoted because you seemed to say that this size_t thing isn't well standardized, which of course is false.

Comment: Of COURSE size_t is standardized ... today.  But there are still a lot of legacy compilers out there that you may not be aware of.  Thus, my comment "this depends on what standard..."

Comment: OK, I rewrote my answer to stress the standard, since this applies to MOST people, but also to clearly call out some very old compilers.  I added some links for documentation.

Comment: Thanks Eddie and all who contributed very insightful information. It is the information particular to embedded and old compilers that will help me a lot.

Comment: Old compilers are very much more common in the embedded world. On the other hand, I have a (running) PDP-11 in my office, and the Decus C compiler for it is of a similar vintage. I don't use it often myself, but it is kept alive for a reason...

Answer (score 1):

Functions normally use a `size_t` to pass a size as parameter. I say normally because `fgets()` uses an `int` parameter, which in my opinion is a flaw in the C standard.

`size_t` is defined as a type which can contain the size (in bytes) of any object you could access. Generally it's a typedef of `unsigned int` or `unsigned long`.
That's why the values returnes by the `sizeof` operator are of `size_t` type.

So 2 ** (`sizeof(size_t)` * `CHAR_BIT`) gives you a maximum amount of memory that your program could handle, but it's certainly not the most precise one.
(`CHAR_BIT` is defined in `limits.h` and yields the number of bits contained in a `char`).

Comment: Isn't CHAR_BIT defined to be 8? Or is char only defined to be 1 byte?

Comment: char = 1 byte, the number of bits may change

Comment: To quote the standard, CHAR_BIT is the “number of bits for smallest object that is not a bit-field (byte)”, and it must be at least 8. An interesting link: http://c-faq.com/charstring/wchar.html.

Comment: And along with `fgets`... While `snprintf` takes a `size_t` argument, it (and all other `printf`-family functions) return an `int`, and it's an error to pass a size argument larger than `INT_MAX` to `snprintf`...

Answer (score 0):

They take a size_t argument; so the it's platform dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation dependent, but you can look in the header (.h) file that you need to include before you can use memcpy.  The declaration will tell you (look for size_t or other).

And then you ask what size_t is, well, that's the implementation dependent part.

Answer (score 0):

Right, you cannot copy areas that are greater then 2^(sizeof(size_t)*8) bytes. But that is nothing to worry about, because you cannot allocate more space either, because `malloc` also takes the size as a size_t parameter.

Comment: I think you mean "2^(sizeof(size_t)*8)".

Comment: Well you can call malloc() multiple times :)

Comment: @aib, Sure, but you won't be guaranteed contiguous buffers.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an issue related to what `size_t` can represent verses what your platform will allow a process to actually address.

Even with virtual memory on a 64-bit platform, you are unlikely to be able to call `memcpy()` with sizes of more than a few TB or so this week, and even then that is a pretty hot machine.... it is hard to imagine what a machine on which it would be possible to install a fully covered 64-bit address space would look like.

Never mind the embedded systems with only a few KB of total writable memory, where it can't make sense to attempt to `memcpy()` more information than the RAM regardless of the definition of `size_t`. Do think about what just happened to the stack holding the return address from that call if you did?

Or systems where the virtual address space seen by a process is smaller than the physical memory installed. This is actually the case with a Win32 process running on a Win64 platform, for example. (I first encountered this under the time sharing OS TSX-11 running on a PDP-11 with 4MB of physical memory, and 64KB virtual address in each process. 4MB of RAM was a lot of memory then, and the IBM PC didn't exist yet.)