# How big can a malloc be in C?

Tags: c, macros, malloc, totalview

I have a malloc in C that is 26901^2*sizeof(double)

This got me thinking what the largest value can be here?

Also, would I have any problems defining a macro to access this 2D array?

```
 #define DN(i,j) ((int)i * ny + (int)j)
```

Because this seems to not be working for me - or I am at least unsure it is. I can't figure out how to make totalview dive on a macro to tell me what A[DN(indx,jndx)] is actually looking at.

Comment: As large as address space and the allocator allow. Finding a very large contiguous block can be difficult, though.

Comment: If you find yourself needing ~10 GB of core, you are probably doing something that could be done more efficiently otherwise. But your question seems to be navel-gazing curiosity. So, on the right machine, you could malloc(∞).

Comment: I tested this once on 64 bit linux, and I could malloc TB's that were not even in the machine, but only in chunks of 43 GB max. (which looked like it was related to the amount of physical ram + swap - a few GB)

Comment: If you want to better see what `A[DN(indx,jndx)]` is looking at using a debugger, make `DN` a function instead of a macro.  You will also gain additional type safety and the ability to use complex statements as arguments without altering the order of operations.

Comment: A thing to remember about linux is that just because the data was 'malloc'ed doesn't mean that there is memory backing it.  You can malloc as much memory as you could possibly want (or the size of the argument that you pass into it), but you might not be able to use all of that memory.  It will back the memory on first access to it. If Linux can't make good on it's memory IOUs it tends to kill programs to get more memory.

Comment: It would be nice to see an answer that actually discusses virtual address mappings, and limits thereabouts, not this guess work below.

Comment: While it may not matter here, your macro is not safe for extremely large values because you're using `int` instead of `size_t`. This could lead to invocation of undefined behavior if the value overflows `INT_MAX`. If nothing else, it unnecessarily restricts the range of sizes you can use. For robust code, you really need to do checking for overflow at some point, even if you do use `size_t`, since just because a, b, and c fit doesn't mean a*b+c fits.

Comment: @Matt Joiner: So who's stopping you?

Comment: This is big.  You need a 64 bit system to do it.

Comment: @msw: Nobody apparently.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

### Observations

Assuming a typical allocator, such as the one glibc uses, there are some observations:

1. Whether or not the memory is actually used, the region must be reserved contiguously in virtual memory.
2. The largest free contiguous regions depends on the memory usage of existing memory regions, and the availability of those regions to [`malloc`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc).
3. The mapping practices depend on the architecture and OS. Furthermore underlying system calls to obtain memory regions are affected by these practices (such as `malloc` calling through to [`mmap`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) to acquire pages).

### Experiment

Here's a [simple program](http://code.google.com/p/anacrolix/source/browse/public/stackoverflow/largest_malloc_size.c) to allocate the largest possible block (compile with `gcc largest_malloc_size.c -Wall -O2`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void *malloc_wrap(size_t size)
{
    void *p = malloc(size);
    if (p) {
        printf("Allocated %zu bytes from %p to %p\n", size, p, p + size);
    }
    else {
        printf("Failed to allocated %zu bytes\n", size);
    }
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    size_t step = 0x1000000;
    size_t size = step;
    size_t best = 0;
    while (step > 0)
    {
        void *p = malloc_wrap(size);
        if (p) {
            free(p);
            best = size;
        }
        else {
            step /= 0x10;
        }
        size += step;
    }
    void *p = malloc_wrap(best);
    if (p) {
        pause();
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Running the above program (`./a.out`) on my `Linux stanley 2.6.32-24-generic-pae #39-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 28 07:39:26 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux` machine obtains this result:

```
<snip>
Allocated 2919235584 bytes from 0x9763008 to 0xb7763008
Allocated 2936012800 bytes from 0x8763008 to 0xb7763008
Failed to allocated 2952790016 bytes
Failed to allocated 2953838592 bytes
Failed to allocated 2953904128 bytes
Failed to allocated 2953908224 bytes
Allocated 2936012800 bytes from 0x85ff008 to 0xb75ff008
```

This is an allocation of exactly 2800MiB. Observing the relevant mapping from [`/proc/[number]/maps`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc):

```
<snip>
0804a000-0804b000 rw-p 00001000 08:07 3413394    /home/matt/anacrolix/public/stackoverflow/a.out
085ff000-b7600000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7600000-b7621000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7621000-b7700000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7764000-b7765000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7765000-b78b8000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 916041     /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
<snip>
bfc07000-bfc1c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
```

### Conclusion

It appears the heap has been expanded in the area between the program data and code, and the shared library mappings, which sit snug against the [user/kernel memory space boundary](http://kerneltrap.org/node/2450) (obviously 3G/1G on this system).

This result suggests that the maximum allocatable space using malloc is roughly equal to:

1. The user space region (3GB in the example)
2. Less the offset to the start of the heap (program code and data)
3. Less the space reserved for the main thread stack
4. Less the space occupied by all the mapped in shared libraries
5. Finally, the largest contiguous region that can be found by the underlying system call within the region available to the heap (which may be fragmented by other mappings)

### Notes

With respect to glibc and Linux implementations, the following manual snippets are of great interest:

[`malloc`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc)

```
   Normally, malloc() allocates memory from the heap, and adjusts the size
   of the heap as required, using sbrk(2).  When allocating blocks of mem‐
   ory larger than MMAP_THRESHOLD bytes, the glibc malloc() implementation
   allocates the memory as a  private  anonymous  mapping  using  mmap(2).
   MMAP_THRESHOLD  is  128  kB  by  default,  but is adjustable using mal‐
   lopt(3).
```

[`mmap`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap)

```
   MAP_ANONYMOUS
          The mapping is not backed by any file; its contents are initial‐
          ized to zero.
```

### Afterword

This test was done on a x86 kernel. I'd expect similar results from a x86_64 kernel, albeit with vastly larger memory regions returned. Other operating systems may vary in their placement of mappings, and the handling of large `malloc`s, so results could be quite considerably different.

Answer (score 11):

That depends on your malloc implementation!

According to Wikipedia, "Since the v2.3 release, the GNU C library (glibc) uses a modified ptmalloc2, which itself is based on dlmalloc v2.7.0."  dlmalloc refers to Doug Lea's malloc implementation.  The important thing to note in this implementation is that large mallocs are accomplished through the operating system's memory mapped file functionality, so these blocks can be quite large indeed without many problems of finding a contiguous block.

Answer (score 7):

The malloc question is answered (depends on OS, which you don't specify), so about that define:

```
#define DN(i,j) ((int)i * ny + (int)j)
```

is not quite safe, for someone might do `DN(a+b,c)` which expands to

```
((int)a+b * ny + (int)c)
```

which is probably not what you wanted. So put a lot of parentheses in there:

```
#define DN(i,j) ((int)(i) * ny + (int)(j))
```

to see what `DN(indx,jndx)` points to, just `printf("%d\n",DN(indx,jndx));`

Comment: Good answer.  Also, those casts the OP had, they look unnecessary and possibly even dangerous.

Comment: If a cast is needed (and it's a big "if", really), they should be casts to an unsigned type, unless additional trickery is used to make the array support negative indices. `size_t` is a good candidate.

Answer (score 1):

The size parameter in a call to malloc is of type size_t, which varies by implementation. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745152/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-buffers-memcpy-memset-etc-can-handle) for more.

Answer (score 1):

> This got me thinking what the largest value can be here?

26'901^2 = 723'663'801. If your double is 8 bytes, then it is less than 8GB. I see totally no problem allocating that much of memory and my apps routinely allocate (on 64 bit systems) much more. (Biggest memory consumption I have ever seen was 420GB (on Solaris 10 numa system with 640GB RAM) with largest continuous block of ~24GB.)

Largest value is hard to identify since it is platform dependent: similar to the 32bit systems it depends on user-space / kernel-space split. As things stand at the moment, I think one would first come to the limit of the actual physical RAM - before reaching the limit of what libc can allocate. (And kernel doesn't care, it just expands virtual memory often without even considering whether there is sufficient RAM to pin it to.)

Answer (score 1):

The largest memory block you can *ask* `malloc()` for is the largest `size_t` value - this is `SIZE_MAX` from `<limits.h>`.  The largest amount you can *sucessfully* request is obviously dependent on the operating system and the configuration of the individual machine.

Your macro is not safe.  It performs the index calculation with an `int` variable, which is only required to have a range up to 32767.  Any value higher than this can cause signed overflow, which results in undefined behaviour.  You are probably best off doing the calculation as a `size_t`, since that type must be able to hold any valid array index:

```
#define DN(i, j) ((size_t)(i) * ny + (size_t)(j))
```

(Although note that if you supply negative values for `i` or `j`, you'll get an index far out of bounds).