# Find largest allocation of memory possible

Tags: c++, c, windows, malloc, new-operator

In 32bit mode application has access to 2GB of virtual address space. How would you find out the maximum size of memory you can allocate to this virtual address space, without malloc or new failing?

For example, lets say you want to take up the whole 2GB of virtual address space, but you just allocated 2MB of data in the middle of the 2GB address space. Is there a Windows API call that you can find out the max concurrent address space that you can allocate? So that when you call malloc or new the call does not fail?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm interested to know how you are going to use this information, how does knowing the amount of available memory help you? If your app *needs* to allocate x-amount of memory and then fails it's not much different to knowing there is not enough and failing. You still fail to get the memory you need.

Comment: Perhaps he's implementing a garbage collector of some sort?

Comment: The problem with any "solution" to this is that whatever figure you get might be outdated the very moment you get it.

Comment: @Toolbox: In which case knowing the largest possible allocation would help him... how?

Comment: @Raedwald, no I would like to know how much space is avaliable without needing to guess it.

Comment: @Chad: Do you want to know how much is available *now*, or how much is available at the time you need it? These two can (and sometimes *will*) be different, even if the allocation comes immediately after the query.

Comment: @Bart It's to find out how much is available now. Please take into consideration that there is no other threads running, nothing else but a simple main. No point querying now then to use the value later on.

Comment: @Chad: There are also no other processes/programs running? Memory is a resource that gets shared between all processes.

Comment: @Bart, there is virtual memory that manages the physical memory the best way it can. Then there is virtual address space that each process receives 2gb of addressable memory (in 32bit mode without /LARGEADDRESSAWARE flag in the linker being enabled). So all I need to find out is the largest free block of address space is available to the process. Yes, Virtual memory means I can use more than avaliable physical memory, and pages are loaded into and out of physical memory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How big can a malloc be in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463207/how-big-can-a-malloc-be-in-c)

Comment: @Chad: Even with virtual memory, the total amount of memory is limited and shared between all processes. In a typical desktop system, the largest block of free address space for an application is larger than the largest block the memory manager will be able to obtain. This is not related to the amount of physical memory, but to the fact that all memory (physical and virtual) is shared between all the processes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Source:
http://www.voyce.com/index.php/2009/08/21/largest-free-block-of-address-space/

```
DWORD FindLargestSizeOfMemory()
{

    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
    DWORD start = 0;
    bool recording = false;
    DWORD freestart = 0, largestFreestart = 0;
    __int64 free = 0, largestFree = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        SIZE_T s = VirtualQuery((LPCVOID)start, &mbi, sizeof(mbi));
        if (s != sizeof(mbi)) break;

    if (mbi.State == MEM_FREE)
        {
            if (!recording) freestart = start;

            free += mbi.RegionSize;
            recording = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (recording)
            {
                if (free > largestFree)
                {
                    largestFree = free;
                    largestFreestart = freestart;
                }
            }
            free = 0;
            recording = false;
        }
        start += mbi.RegionSize;
    }

  return largestFree;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might never get a satisfactory answer. The largest allocatable memory block is dependend on memory fragmentation and can be altered with memory defragmentation tools, different memory managers, different boot time switches (e.g. /3GB on windows) or even a reboot.

I'm not sure what you mean by "without malloc or new failing", do you not have access to malloc? Because the correct way to do this would be to allocate memory using var=malloc(...) in incrementing steps and looking for the step where var is null.

I am pretty sure that the information you seek can only be determined by probing for it. The information is always in fluid motion by allocation and deallocation of running processes, it could only be a snapshot of the current situation, and of course, for taking the snapshot, all processes would have to be suspended temporarily. So the information you would get after Windows scanning for a result and returning it to you would not be accurate or resilient, as the structure of the memory allocation could very well have changed by now.

Comment: *"using `var=malloc(...)` in incrementing steps"*, so you might create fragmentation...

Answer (score 0):

You could use [VirtualQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to query the possible pages and see if they return `MEM_FREE`.

Comment: Not entirely accurate, as the CRT may allocate a page but not be using all of it and have the rest available for use.