# How To increase input size of program

Tags: c

This program takes two input . first Array size(n) and choice
ex:- if n is 100 than my program generate 100 random numbers and sort them using merge 
sort and quick sort.

Now if you enter choice==2 than it display time taken by both sorting algorithm

My program works upto input size 10^8 but I want it to work upto 10"10 .If i enter input size 10^9 it gives segmentation fault . there is problem in allocation that much amount of memory .malloc returns null if input size exceeds 10^9

Can anyone please tell me how can I improve my program's input size...........

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

long long merge(int *A,long long i,long long mid,long long j)                   

{   

int *C;
C=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*(j-i+1));                           
long long  r,start,k;
r=0;
start=i;
k=mid+1;
while((i<=mid)&&(k<=j))
{
    if(A[i]>A[k])
    {
        C[r]=A[k];
        r++;k++;
    }
    else
    {
        C[r]=A[i];
        r++;i++;
    }
}
while(i<=mid)
{
    C[r]=A[i];
    r++;i++;
}
while(k<=j)
{
    C[r]=A[k];
    r++;k++;
}
for(i=0;i<r;i++,start++)
    A[start]=C[i];
free(C);
  }
   long long partition(int *A,long long i,long long j)                           
   {

long long mid;
mid=(i+j)/2;                                    
if(i<j)
{
    partition(A,i,mid);                         
    partition(A,mid+1,j);
    merge(A,i,mid,j);                       
}
    }

    long long find_position(int A[],long long i,long long j)                        

    {

long long pivot,temp,end;
end=j;
pivot=i;
while(i<j)
{
    while(A[i]<=A[pivot]&&i<end)
        i++;
    while(A[j]>A[pivot])
        j--;
    if(i<j)
    {
        temp=A[i];
        A[i]=A[j];
        A[j]=temp;
    }
}
temp=A[pivot];
A[pivot]=A[j];
A[j]=temp;
return j;
  } 
  long long quicksort(int A[],long long  i,long long  j)                                
  {
long long position;
if(j>i)
{
    position = find_position(A,i,j);
    quicksort(A,i,position-1);
    quicksort(A,position+1,j);
  }
    }
   int main()
  {
clock_t start,end,quick_sort,merge_sort;
long long input_size,i;
int choice,x;
srand(time(NULL));
printf("Enter input Size\n");
scanf("%lld",&input_size);
int *A,*B;
printf("input your choice\n");
scanf("%d",&choice);
A=(int *)malloc(input_size*sizeof(int));
B=(int *)malloc(input_size*sizeof(int));
if(A==NULL||B==NULL)
{
    printf("sorry that much memory can't be allocated\n");
    return 0;
}
for(i=0;i<input_size;i++)
{
    x=rand();
    A[i]=x;
    B[i]=x;
}
if(choice==1)
{
    printf("Array entered by user\n");
    for(i=0;i<input_size;i++)
        printf("%d  ",A[i]);
}
start=clock();
partition(A,0,input_size-1);
end=clock();
merge_sort=end-start;
if(choice==2)
    printf("\n time taked by merge sort is %6.6f",((double)(merge_sort)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
if(choice==1)
{
    printf("\nmerge sorted array\n");
    for(i=0;i<input_size;i++)
        printf("%d  ",A[i]);
}
start=clock();
quicksort(B,0,input_size-1);
end=clock();
quick_sort=end-start;
if(choice==2)
    printf("\n time taked by quick sort is %6.6f",((double)(quick_sort)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
if(choice==1)
{
    printf("\nquick sorted array\n");
    for(i=0;i<input_size;i++)
        printf("%d  ",B[i]);
}
printf("\n");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: what operating system and compiler?

Comment: It's probably going over a 2GB limit.

Comment: When I see this: `mid=(i+j)/2;` (although you are using `long long`) it always remind me this: http://googleresearch.blogspot.ch/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html

Comment: 10 ^ 10 should be no problem with a 64 bits machine and let's say 96GB RAM (10 billion ints = 40GB, which you allocate **twice**).  32 bits machines can only access 2GB work memory.  You should probably rethink your problem, this ain't gonna work...

Comment: @fvu there's an "edit" option for comments.

Comment: @H2CO3 I know but it has a 5 minute window in which edits are allowed, and it was only afterwards that I saw he wants in fact 10^10 ints * 2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The max allocatable size is 2GB for malloc(which takes size_t). Hence your program crashes. I am assuming you're on a 32 bit machine.

Please see below link to learn more about it and test if you can actually allocate that much memory.

[How Big can a malloc be in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463207/how-big-can-a-malloc-be-in-c)

To get around this, you will need to write your own VIRTUAL MEMORY MANAGER and MEMORY ALLOCATOR using binary files and write your own `free()` and `malloc()` routines.

See here for an example(this is for iPhones only): [Create your own VMM](http://insanelyi.com/topic/10039-how-to-create-your-own-virtual-memory-on-any-iphone-ipod-touch-over-80-mb-of-ram/)

Comment: So what's the solution.Should I run my program on 64 bit machine.

Comment: I am using ubuntu(32 bit),gcc compiler.

Comment: @stranger001 yes the solution is to run it in a 64 bit machine with more than 6-8GB RAM. But to remain architecture independent(that is runnable on 32 and 64 bit) yu might have to write your own VMM and malloc()/free()

Answer (score 0):

You need to take into account that the address range can be 32bit or 64 bit and some of that is required for the stack, other variables, housekeeping etc. In addition many (all?) OS have soft and hard limits to prevent a process soaking up all the physical and swap memory.

Anyway why are you doing this?

Comment: He is probably coding a megavirus that will crash all our systems and then he will call in for firesale and take over our worlds. I probably think its homework or a question posed by an interviewer or something.

Comment: Personally I hate those interview questions. I have posed some questions for interview. The person is nervous so why the hell do you what to prove thhhat you are a bright spark? I think it is better to get a better candidate to test his or her knowledge on the subect. For example what does a pointer mean?

Comment: Personally I like to test people on what they already know and how they would solve a tricky problem. The solution is simple but the question will trick the candidate. It tests how they will perform under pressure and how fast they can think.

Comment: @PrototypeStark - You are in the middle of a chess board and you can walk four squares where are you?

Comment: in the middle of a chess board

Comment: Why bother on the technical stuff. That is easy to prove one way or the other. But will that person get one with the team? That question is most illuminating.

Comment: I agree. Its important to understand who will fit in and who will not.