# Integer overflow while malloc memory

Tags: c, debugging, buffer-overflow, integer-overflow

We have struct image pointer:

```
struct image {
uint16_t size_x;
uint16_t size_y;
struct pixel *px;
};
```

and:

```
  img->px = malloc(sizeof(struct pixel) * height * width);
```

where pixel:

```
struct pixel {
   uint8_t red;
   uint8_t green;
   uint8_t blue;
   uint8_t alpha;
   }
```

where width & height:

```
  long height = strtol(height_arg, &end_ptr, 10);
  long width = strtol(width_arg, &end_ptr, 10);
```

So, since we use malloc() to allocate memory and it uses size_t for allocating.
Since we multiplying height and width which are long typed to allocate memory, is there integer overflow expected? If, yes then how to handle it?

Later on we iterate over picture and color it:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < img->size_y; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < img->size_x; j++) {
         image_data[i][j].red = palette[0].red;
         image_data[i][j].green = palette[0].green;
         image_data[i][j].blue = palette[0].blue;
         image_data[i][j].alpha = 0xff;
      }
  }
```

where

```
 img->size_x = width;
 img->size_y = height;
```

Comment: If you don't check the values beforehand then of course

Comment: The `sizeof` operator returns a `size_t` type; if that is `unsigned long long` (it may be), then the multiplication will be performed as `long long`.

Comment: What possible values can you get for `width` and `height`? What are your requirements and limitations for the dimensions?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude There are no limitations since my goal is to find way to attack the program, find bug. And then fix it

Comment: @Devolus Yes, for pixels

Comment: On computers all integer types are limited. The limit might be very high (as is the case for 64 bit integers) but there still is a limit. It will always be possible to go over that limit if the code doesn't have checks for it. And the checks have to be from the user inputs. It doesn't matter if the input is read from a file, from a GUI, a text-based console, socket or any other way. If the input comes from outside the program it's "user" input that must be validated.

Comment: @AdrianMole: In `unsigned long long * long long * long long`, the `long long` operands are converted to `unsigned long long`. Both multiplications are done as `unsigned long long`, not `long long`.

Comment: Updated code for pixels!

Comment: @Eric Thanks for clarifying that. Integer conversions with mixed signed/unsigned operands still give me issues.

Comment: @Devolus Multiplying two 16-bit values gives a 16-bit result, which could overflow leading to problems in further calculations using that result.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Re “On computers all integer types are limited”: Not on my Turing machine. It just prints a message on the console asking the operator to insert another tape.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Well there's still a limit... How much tape can be manufactured in a limited universe? :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's why we need a multiverse ;)

Comment: Can any random integer arithmetic expression in C overflow? Yes, it can. Why we need to be aware of the maximum values of every variable type involved, every single time we write an expression.

Answer (score 2):

Integer overflow may happen at every point of this program:

```
strtol("9999999999", &end_ptr, 10) -> will overflow and return LONG_MAX
height * width -> can overflow and return a negative value (since those are signed longs)
sizeof(struct pixel) * height * width 
-> can return a bigger value than UNSIGNED_MAX, wrapping around to a smaller value than expected
```

Malloc can allocate some [very large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463207/how-big-can-a-malloc-be-in-c) data segments, and may not fail immediately, so you should seriously consider verifying your results before allocating.

Comment: Unless `size_t` is narrower than the size of `height` and `width`, `sizeof(struct pixel) * height * width` cannot overflow in the same way as `height * width` as `sizeof` is unsigned, so it differs in that the operation is defined to wrap (not overflow) and cannot return a negative value (since none is representable).

Comment: @EricPostpischil Which is why I mentioned  "returning a smaller value than expected". Wrapping around is still considered an overflow, no?
Sorry if it was unclear

Comment: The C standard specifically uses “overflow” to mean the ideal result of an operation is not representable in the type, and it **defines** unsigned arithmetic to wrap, meaning the ideal result is the wrapped result. C 2018 6.2.5 9 explicitly states “A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow,…”

Comment: Ah, my bad, fixed the answer, thanks for the lesson

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a risk.

You can check it like this:

```
struct pixel *px;    

if (height > SIZE_MAX / width || sizeof *px  > SIZE_MAX / (width * height)) {
    // Handle overflow
} 

px = malloc(sizeof *px * width * height);

if(!px) {
    // Handle allocation error
}

img->px = px;
```

Comment: You also need to factor in the `sizeof(struct pointer)`

Comment: @MarkEzberg You should also consider that `width` and `height` can also be 0 or negative. Also, you won't want to allocate `SIZE_MAX` amount of bytes. The best solution is to just predefine and check for a reasonable limit to the size of an image, and this should be less than any potential overflow (which is technically a wrapping around of the value, not an overflow, if you want to be pedantic)