# Can I allocate more than 65535 bytes according C standards?

Tags: c, malloc, size-t

`malloc` defined like below:

```
void *malloc(size_t size);
```

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html

---

`size_t` definition (stddef.h):

`size_t: Unsigned integer type of the result of the sizeof operator.`
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/basedefs/stddef.h.html

---

But according this page, max limitation of `size_t` is 65535.
(Section Limits of Other Integer Types):

Limit of size_t: SIZE_MAX 65535
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/stdint.h.html

---

Does it mean I can not allocate more than 65535 bytes when I want to respect C standard?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745152/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-buffers-memcpy-memset-etc-can-handle

Comment: `size_t` must be able to represent anything that `sizeof` may return. What is `sizeof(int[(unsigned) -1])` on a 32 bit system? And on a 64 bit system?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SIZE_MAX` must be at least 65535. If you're running something like MS-DOS, chances are it'll actually even be that small. On a typical, reasonably current desktop computer (say, anything less than 10 years old) you can expect it to be larger, typically at least around 4 billion (2<sup>32</sup>-1, to be more exact).

Whether you need to (try to) deal with a more limited system will depend on the range of targets to which you might care about porting your code. If you really might need to deal with a 16-bit compiler on a system with less than, say, 1 megabyte of addressable memory, then you'll have to write your code with that in mind. In all honesty, however, for most people that's simply irrelevant -- even relatively small portable systems (e.g., an iPod) can address far more memory than that any more. OTOH, if you're writing code for a singing greeting card, then yes, such limitations probably come with the territory (but in such cases, the standard is often something to treat more as a general guideline than an absolute law).

Comment: But POSIX definition says, limit, meaning maximum limit. Also why did they define it as 65535? If something depends on the data type size, generally the standard doesn't specify such explicit limits

Comment: @PavanManjunath: I'm not sure about the wording in POSIX, but in the C standard it says (§7.18.3/2): "Its implementation-defined value shall be equal to or greater in magnitude (absolute value) than the corresponding value given below, with the same sign." So the 65535 is the *minimum* value allowed, not the maximum.

Comment: @PavanManjunath: You're simply misreading POSIX. Just like C, POSIX defines the "minimum maximum", i.e. the minimum value that an implementation is allowed to impose as the maximum. It's also probably a mistake that POSIX still allows `SIZE_MAX` to be so small, since (1) POSIX now requires `int` to be at least 32-bit, and (2) it's impossible to implement POSIX in under 64k, much less have room left for an application to run.

Answer (score 3):

The minimum value of `SIZE_MAX` is 65535 but it can (and usually is) be more.

On most non-embedded platforms, `size_t` is a `typedef` for `unsigned long` and `SIZE_MAX` is set to `ULONG_MAX`.

Comment: Do you mean I should check `SIZE_MAX` before memory allocation (`malloc`)?

Comment: If you are using a `32-bit` or a `64-bit` platform I think it is safe to assume `SIZE_MAX` is at least `UINT_MAX`.

Comment: @AmirSaniyan: This is no more a problem than the general need for you to know whether your data types can actually represent the values that you want to put in them.  You don't have to *check* anything per se, since a variable of type `size_t` will always have a 'valid' value, but of course you must understand whether or not you're overflowing anything.

Answer (score 1):

On a 32-bit platform SIZE_MAX is usually 2^32 - 1 and on a 64 bit platform it is 2^64 - 1. Check with a printf if unsure.

```
printf("sizeof size_t = %zx, SIZE_MAX = %zx\n", sizeof(size_t), SIZE_MAX);
```

Include stdint.h to get the value of SIZE_MAX.

Comment: The correct prefix for printing `size_t` is `z` in modern C, `%zu` or `%zx`.